# How can I use 2 different login managers with flask-login if my website should be accessible from the browser and from some APIs?

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-login

I'm developing a website with Flask and it's composed of two parts, a user-facing GUI and some APIs.

At the moment the user-facing part uses [the standard process to authenticate a user](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works) and the APIs should use the [suggested way to authenticate the users with APIs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#custom-login-using-request-loader).

Both ways look pretty easy to use, but I'm not really sure about how can I use them together in my application to differentiate between the 2 use cases.

Any idea?

Is there any different approach I may consider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two different loaders.

Flask-Login calls a function decorated with `user_loader` when there is a cookie. If there are no cookies provided, a function decorated with `request_loader` is called [[1](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/e4ad58afb8f8563de67cd6b860e68bda8165cb92/flask_login/login_manager.py#L334)].

Quick example:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user

lm = LoginManager()

users_by_id = {1: User(id=1, username='FirstUser')}
users_by_key = {'xxxyyyzzz': User(id=2, username='SecondUser')}

@lm.user_loader
def load_user(user_
    anon = User(id=0, username='Anonymous')
    return users_by_id.get(int(user_id), anon)


@lm.request_loader
def load_user(request):
    anon = User(id=0, username='Anonymous')
    header = request.headers.get('Auth', None)
    if not header:
        return anon

    return users_by_key.get(header, anon)


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    lm.init_app(app)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return 'Hello, {}'.format(current_user)

    @app.route('/login/')
    def login():
        session['user_id'] = 1
        return 'Logged in'

    return app


app = create_app()
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key'
app.run()
```

Now you can go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/ with your browser and "log in", and then an index page will correctly address you as a FirstUser.
Then, you can send a request and authenticate via a header, like this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', headers={'Auth': 'xxxyyyzzz'})
>>> r.text
"Hello, User('SecondUser')"
```

Comment: I tried to add both loaders but the request_loader is not called at all. Any possible reason?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that a cookie is sent, and therefore `request_loader` is skipped. How do you make an API request?
I will update my answer with a small example.

Comment: It was that indeed. Thank you very much.